# Handing over polygon attribute to new point while digitizing

Tags: qgis, intersection, spatialite, trigger

My task is to work with bird observation data in an area, that is divided into zones as different polygons (A1, A2, etc.).

I have the hand-written lists of observations and want to bring all entries into a database. My idea was to create a point feature somewhere in the corresponding zone for each line, and then enter all data that is provided (Species, number, begin of observation, end of observation, etc ...) with a custom form.

I also need to have the polygon ID in the data, which I of course could enter manually, but I would rather prefer to learn how to include it automagically by querying to position of the point over the polygon and extract the polygon ID somehow.

As I want to work with a spatialite database, i thought about creating a trigger that queries the polygon the new point is created above and include the ID in my point data.

How do I start because I cannot find examples on that?

[image: My areas and some points]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a polygon table in a SpatiaLite database named "polys" with an id column, "poly_id", and a points table "pts", also with a column "poly_id, then add a trigger as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_poly_id AFTER INSERT ON pts FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE pts SET poly_id=(SELECT poly_id FROM polys WHERE ST_Contains(polys.geometry, pts.geometry));
END
```

Now, each time you insert into the point layer (and save edits), the poly_id column will automatically get the value of the poly_id from it's containing polygon.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use a view instead of a database trigger. The simple reason is that when the polygon layer is updated, all point attributes in the view will still be correct. Instead, if you use a trigger, changes will not be updated. Of course it could be that that's the behavior you want - then triggers would be fine - but it still causes duplication of information in your database.